# How do I get company mode to recognize clang?

Tags: company-mode, c++

My current setup is as follows

Elementary OS Freya

- Emacs version 24.5.1
- company-mode 0.8.12
- clang-3.5-dev
- libclang-3.5-dev

I've checked that both libclang-3.5-dev and clang-3.5-dev are installed
and I have also checked that clang was in /usr/bin. There is no problem on init but when I open a cpp file the following error in thrown

```
Company back-end 'company-clang' could not be initialized:                                     
Company found no clang executable
```

I'm trying to setup a C/C++ development environment in emacs, I was following [this](http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html) guide in order to achieve this.

i.e adding the following to my .emacs file

```
(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(setq company-backends (delete 'company-semantic company-backends))
(define-key c-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete)
(define-key c++-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete)
```

So how do I get clang recognized by company-clang?

Comment: Try using `M-x customize-variable RET company-clang-executable RET` and setting its value to the path to your executable.

Comment: thank you @elethan for your valuable insight! I was able to fix the problem by creating a symbolic link to the `clang-3.5` named `clang`. Setting the correct path to the executable did not work which suggested that company-clang was looking for the wrong file. I was able to find the name of the file company-clang was looking for using `M-x find-variable`, and created a symbolic link to match to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP here, my clang executable wasn't being recognized by `company-clang` because the name of the executable in my `/usr/bin` was  `clang-3.5` and not `clang`.

1. Using `M-x customize-variable RET company-clang-executable RET` as @elethan suggested and setting the absolute path to the clang executable didn't resolve the problem.
2. Above suggested that `company-clang` was searching in the right place (*directory*) but not searching for the right file (*clang executable*)
3. I used `M-x find-variable RET company-clang-executable RET` to find out the name of the file `company-clang` was looking.
4. From `company-clang.el`, we can see that `company-clang` is looking for a file named `clang`
5. In `/usr/bin` I created a symbolic link to my `clang-3.5` named `clang` using the following command

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang-3.5 clang
   ```

***TL;DR***

1. My clang executable was not named `clang`
2. Created a symbolic link named `clang` to my clang executable
3. `company-clang` finds clang executable